# How do I add Javascript to every non-admin page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin that I previously was only needing to load Javascript on content pages.  In other words, the code `add_filter('the_content', 'insert_js');` was sufficient.  Now I'd like the Javascript to be inserted to every page that isn't an admin page or a search result page and I was wondering if there was a shortcut filter name for that or if I have to list all the filters.  I also only want the Javascript to be added to the page once.  If I have to add a few `add_filter()` lines, that's fine, but I am still unsure of what they need to be.  I consulted the Plugin API/Filter Reference documentation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and that seemed ambiguous.  I also tried using **the_category** amongst others to no avail.  I am also trying to figure out how to get the Javascript to load on the homepage.  The Javascript I am including is not static and needs to be generated based on some WP specific attributes known at runtime (like URL).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: have you checked answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to @itskawsar's answer; you can wrap the `wp_enqueue_script()` functions in a conditional to make sure they only load on non-admin pages:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script', // handle
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', // src
        array( 'jquery' ) // dependencies   
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `add_action` to add script to specific hook. Generally `wp_head` used to add script to head section and `wp_footer` is used to add script at footer section.
Check following code:

```
<?php

function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        [YOUR JS CODE HERE]
    </script>
<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

Or you can use `wp_enqueue_script()` to add external script like following:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script', // handle
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', // src
    array( 'jquery' ) // dependencies
  );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

You can find more details about `wp_enqueue_scripts` on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script